# How to get a mock object into onCreate() of an Activity?

Tags: android, automated-tests

I have an Activity which uses an object. For testing I want to mock this object but I can not find how to make an Activity use the mock object in the onCreate() function.

I am using AndroidMock to create the mock object and Robotium in the tests. For example:

*Application* (standard Android project) :

```
class MainActivity extends ... {
    MyObject obj;
    MainActivity() {
        obj = new MyObject();
    }
    void onCreate(Bundle b) {
        obj.doSomething();
        ...
    }
}
```

*Test* (standard Android Test project) :

```
class MainActivityTest extends ... {
    @UsesMocks(MyObject.class)
    public void testMyObject() {
        // create the mock object
        MyObject o = AndroidMock.createMock(MyObject.class);
        AndroidMock.expect(o.doSomething()).andReturn(false);
        AndroidMock.replay(o);

        // Here some code which makes the activity use the mock object
        // and calls the onCreate() function on the activity.

        // Do some tests on the activity.
        Solo solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
        Assert.assertTrue(solo.searchText("It works!")); 
        AndroidMock.verify(o);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I know the 2 ways.

1. using DI Conrainer. 
   [Robojuice](http://code.google.com/p/roboguice/)

   ```
   @inject
   MyObject obj;
   ```
2. to inherit the Class that be tested

activity

```
    class DummyMainActivity extends MainActivity {
        Bundle b;
        @Override
        void onCreate(Bundle b) {
            this.b = b;
        }
        void onCreateSuper() {
            super(b);
        }
    }
```

test

```
    class MainActivityTest extends ActivityUnitTestCase<DummyMainActivity> {
        @UsesMocks(MyObject.class)
        public void testMyObject() {
             // create the mock object
             MyObject o = AndroidMock.createMock(MyObject.class);

            DummyMainActivity activity = startActivity(new Intent(), null, null);
            activity.obj = o;

            activity.onCreateSuper();
            AndroidMock.verify(o);
        }
    }
```